# clicking buttons on a web page

Tags: bots, clicking

I am trying to make a simple bot that clicks 3 to 4 different buttons on a particular web page. Now I can simply do this with a macro but I wanna take it to a new level with actually making a .exe out of this. I'm using Netbean to write this and it's given me some insight, but it lacks any tutorials.

Any insight for a hopeful future coder would help! I am somewhat a total noob at coding but have made a few minor ones 13 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using? If you're not opposed to NodeJS, then look at ElectronJS, this will allow you to create cross-platform applications (.exe, .dmg etc.) just writing JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

https://electronjs.org

Comment: in netbean im using Java application

Comment: that is a bit different than what i want. i just wanna make a clicking script that runs on a particular web page. it clicks 2 things constantly then every so often it picks between 2 stats. then just a pause feature that i can use to pause the macro. other than that i can build a Gui for this script that part is simple and i can compile it to a .exe or a batch file if needed. i just need a few pointers on where to start to set this thing up... before when i made this i believe i used autoIT and i used a feature getelementbyname(); something similar.